# Visual Studio 2012 - Export Template automation

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012

In previous versions of VS, you could use ProjectGen.exe to automate the export. Is this still possible in VS 2012? I can't find projectgen.exe or any documentation explaining how this might be done. I have several projects and it is tedious to export each one.

Comment: I ended up creating a CodedUI recording and with some modifications I was able to automate the whole multi-project export process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it still technically works, BUT it isn't smart about NuGet so it's not super useful. We are working on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Good to know something is in the works.  In the meantime, in theory I could use it on a VS2012 project to get the .zip, extract it to the file system, modify the vstemplate file to include the necessary nuget stuff, rezip and use that as a target for a VSIX project?  Sounds like a good weekend project.